# Why getCurrentPosition() fails after unlocking gps acces in googleChromeAndroid

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome, gps

I'm implementing some welcome messages to my site that show up at the beginning if the user hasn't enabled the Gps.

The thing is that after enabling the GPS via chrome UI js still can't access the gps postion (keep getting unables alerts on my web page). If page is reloaded then I can.

Is there a way to update the state of the blocking/nonblocking option without refreshing the whole web page ?

```
<script>

    var button = document.getElementById("button");

    button.onclick = function() {

        var geoSuccess = function (position) {
            var startPos = position;
            alert("longlat" + startPos.coords.longitude);
        };
        var geoError = function (error) {
             alert("unable");
        };

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess, geoError);
 };

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check out this link :-   [GPS](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp)    I do not know whether that is what you asked for but I can just tell it to you .It might help Please forgive me if that is irrelevant.  The code is here :

```
         <span id="demo" />
        <script>
          var x = document.getElementById("demo");
          function getLocation() {
          if (navigator.geolocation) {
         navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        } else {
       x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
        }
        }
      function showPosition(position) {
         x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
       "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
        }
    </script>
```

The code above does the following :

- Check if Geolocation is supported
  If supported, run the getCurrentPosition() method. If not, display a message to the user .
- If the getCurrentPosition() method is successful, it returns a coordinates object to the function specified in the parameter ( showPosition )
- NOTE : The showPosition() function gets the displays the Latitude and Longitude

Comment: Hi Tilak Madichetti, i've simplyfied the code in order to make it more readable, i'm not wandering about the browser ability to get gps but about the fact that most users decline the gps via web browser and then they have to enable it again and I can't notice it unless i refresh the whole web page.

Comment: So what you can do is , write a small javascript to refresh the web page automatically onLoad() . So that time can the user notice it ?You can kind of use Jquery too for maing the work easy . if you want me to give the code , I can do it .(I know this is nasty but I do not have any other solution ) .